# android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2..how to give the second item?

Tags: android, json

```
protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
     super.onPostExecute(result);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,titles);
//I want also to give the dates beside titles but it is giving me error
    lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

I used `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` to take two textViews but how to initialize the second one?

Comment: You have to create custom adapter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755440/how-to-display-multiple-number-of-textviews-inside-each-row-in-listview

Comment: okay I will check it..thank u..but my question, there is no way without a custom adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListAdapter` like below or Use CustomAdpater

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
             this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
             mCursor,     
             new String[] {"", ""}, 
             new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}); 


setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: mCursor for what?

Comment: thank u but where i must initialize mCursor? and its for what?

Comment: Error:(170, 21) error: incompatible types: MainActivity.ProcessInBackground cannot be converted to Context